# Python one 'for' loop, multiple dictionary appends

Tags: python, loops, append

```
com = self.get_scan_companies()

    for name in com:
        k.append({'org_id' : None, 'keyword' : name['names']})

    for domain in com:
        k.append({'org_id' : None, 'keyword' : domain['domains']})

    for ip in com:
        k.append({'org_id' : None, 'keyword' : ip['Ips']})
```

`com` generates a dictionary of `{id,'names','domains','Ips'}`
Note: `com` has 4 items but I need the last 3 only.

I want to enhance the code to one `for` loop with 3 lines of appends as above:

```
for name,domain,ip in com:
   k.append({'org_id' : None, 'keyword' : name['names']})
   k.append({'org_id' : None, 'keyword' : domain['domains']})
   k.append({'org_id' : None, 'keyword' : ip['Ips']})
```

Expected result is a list:

```
k=[{'org_id' : None, 'keyword' : name['names']}, {'org_id' : None, 'keyword' : domain['domains']},{'org_id' : None, 'keyword' : ip['Ips']}]
```

I understand the above does not generate the result! Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to iterate through two lists in parallel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1663807/how-to-iterate-through-two-lists-in-parallel)

Comment: well the difference is that in my example it's extraction from one loop' results into different appends. thanks for the try!

Answer (score 0):

The three for loops are all iterating over the same data.  Calling the iterators name, domain, or ip makes no difference.  This would be equivalent to the following single for loop using iter_ as a generic iterator:

```
com = self.get_scan_companies()

for iter_ in com:
   k.append({'org_id' : None, 'keyword' : iter_['names']})
   k.append({'org_id' : None, 'keyword' : iter_['domains']})
   k.append({'org_id' : None, 'keyword' : iter_['Ips']})
```